# How to show an element at its full height?

Tags: html, css

I have a child element (fixed position) inside a parent element (relative position), both of them are inside a wrapper.

When I scroll down the parent that goes behind the child, I can't see the full text inside the parent, instead it gets hidden behind the child.

HTML:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.wrap {
  width: 30em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="parent">
    Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default
    model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like) It is a long established fact that
    a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look
    like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the
    years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that
    it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and
    a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like) It is a long established fact that a reader will
    be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable
    English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes
    by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
    normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem
    ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like) It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the
    readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop
    publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes
    on purpose (injected humour and the like). It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using

    <div class="child">
      footer
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Here is a fiddle to a live preview :
http://jsfiddle.net/59haqofd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a calculated height, like so:

```
  .wrap{
    width:30em;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    z-index:3;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    height:  calc(100% - 60px);
    overflow:  auto;
  }

.parent {
    position: relative;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .child {
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59haqofd/20/

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could give your parent a `padding-bottom` equivalent to the height of your fixed element. (`60px`)

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.wrap {
  width: 30em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="parent">
    Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default
    model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like) It is a long established fact that
    a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look
    like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the
    years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that
    it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and
    a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like) It is a long established fact that a reader will
    be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable
    English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes
    by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
    normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem
    ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like) It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the
    readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop
    publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes
    on purpose (injected humour and the like). It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using

    <div class="child">
      footer
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats the behavior of a fixed element. It positions itself to a fixed position on the viewport.

What are you trying to accomplish instead? Do you want the child element (footer) to always be on the bottom? In that case, use relative instead.